# Databases to practice with

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am looking for either databases that I can download for sqlite3 or csv files to practice with. I was looking at some of the databases on a government website like this.

```
series_id   year    period  value   footnote_codes
CUURA000AA0         1986    M12        100.0              
CUURA000AA0         1987    M01        100.6
```

Something like this would be good, but I am looking for something with values that would be more meaningful to me and could be used to practice different SQL statements and functions with. Basically I just need some big file to use as a database, so that I do not have to create my own.

Comment: Practice how?  You don't need a big huge one if you're just learning.  Why not create one?  That will show you how to do it?

Comment: Do you have a music collection? I enjoyed playing around with the sqlite database that banshee built from my mp3 files.

Comment: I have a pretty big music collection. I wasn't aware that I could do something like that with banshee. I'll be sure to try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com) lets you query the full set of StackOverflow data, it's an excellent learning set and you can see the same data on the site.  Data is dumped once a month I believe.

Comment: I just tried out what you suggested. It does seem like a good learning tool, but is it possible to actually download this data. It might be a little quicker if that were possible.

Comment: Nevermind. I found it http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

**Northwind database for Sqlite**

[Northwind.Sqlite3.sql](http://code.google.com/p/northwindextended/downloads/detail?name=Northwind.Sqlite3.sql&can=2&q=)